# How to make the year-on-year average function more efficient and return the correct result?

Tags: r

I have this df:

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C"),
                     colB = c("Stringn","Stringc","Stringb"),
                     x2008 = c(2.71,3.1,6.21),
                     x2009 = c(1.72,1.68,6.18),
                     x2010 = c(1.32,2.66,4.21))
```

| colA | colB | x2008 | x2009 | x2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Stringn | 2.71 | 1.72 | 1.32 |
| B | Stringc | 3.1 | 1.68 | 2.66 |
| C | Stringd | 6.21 | 6.18 | 4.21 |

I created this function: #A brief definition of what the YOY function should solve [click](https://www.insee.fr/en/metadonnees/definition/c1373) . An example of your application [worldbank](https://tcdata360.worldbank.org/indicators/hb32fc8dc?country=USA&indicator=599&viz=line_chart&years=2007,2017).

```
#how calc year-on-year average 
YOY<-function(df,n=c(1:6)){
  x=rownames(t(as.data.frame(df)[3:dim(df)[2]]))
  y=c(t(as.data.frame(df)[3:dim(df)[2]]))
  df = data.frame(x,y)
  df<-df[c(n),]
  df<-round(transform(df, new.col=c(NA,y[-1]/y[-nrow(df)]-1))[3]*100,2)
  return(round(sum(df[,1],na.rm = T)/(dim(df)[1]-1),2))
}
```

I apply the function YOY:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(`yoy %`=YOY(.,n=c(1:3)))
```

Return:

| colA | colB | x2008 | x2009 | x2010 | `yoy %` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Stringn | 2.71 | 1.72 | 1.32 | -29.9 |
| B | Stringc | 3.1 | 1.68 | 2.66 | -29.9 |
| C | Stringd | 6.21 | 6.18 | 4.21 | -29.9 |

Expected return:

| colA | colB | x2008 | x2009 | x2010 | `yoy %` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Stringn | 2.71 | 1.72 | 1.32 | -29.9 |
| B | Stringc | 3.1 | 1.68 | 2.66 | 6.26 |
| C | Stringd | 6.21 | 6.18 | 4.21 | -16.18 |

Any idea how to solve this problem? How to make the YOY function more efficient and return the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating custom function or even reshaping the data

```r
df <- data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C"),
                 colB = c("Stringn","Stringc","Stringb"),
                 x2008 = c(2.71,3.1,6.21),
                 x2009 = c(1.72,1.68,6.18),
                 x2010 = c(1.32,2.66,4.21))

library(tidyverse) # only dplyr used here

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(YOY = {x <- c_across(starts_with('x'));
  l <- length(x);
  mean((x[-1] - x[-l])*100/x[-l])})

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   colA  colB    x2008 x2009 x2010    YOY
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A     Stringn  2.71  1.72  1.32 -29.9 
#> 2 B     Stringc  3.1   1.68  2.66   6.26
#> 3 C     Stringb  6.21  6.18  4.21 -16.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C"),
                 colB = c("Stringn","Stringc","Stringb"),
                 x2008 = c(2.71,3.1,6.21),
                 x2009 = c(1.72,1.68,6.18),
                 x2010 = c(1.32,2.66,4.21))


#temporary value to hold yearly calculations
temp<-sapply(c(3:(ncol(df)-1)), function(x) {
   #next year/current year
   # converted to precent
   (df[ ,(x+1)]/df[,x]-1)*100
})


df$yoy <- round(rowMeans(temp),2)
df

  colA    colB x2008 x2009 x2010    yoy
1    A Stringn  2.71  1.72  1.32 -29.89
2    B Stringc  3.10  1.68  2.66   6.26
3    C Stringb  6.21  6.18  4.21 -16.18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('x')) %>%
  group_by(colA, colB)%>%
  summarise(val = mean(tail(value, -1)/head(value, -1) - 1) * 100) %>%
  right_join(df)

 colA  colB       val x2008 x2009 x2010
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     Stringn -29.9   2.71  1.72  1.32
2 B     Stringc   6.26  3.1   1.68  2.66
3 C     Stringb -16.2   6.21  6.18  4.21
```

If using R>4.1.0 and you decide to abuse the language, you could do:

```
df |>
  reshape(3:ncol(df), dir = 'long', sep='', idvar = 'colA', v.names = 'value') |>
  stats:::aggregate.formula(formula = value~colA+colB, 
                            FUN = \(x) mean(tail(x,-1)/head(x,-1) - 1)*100) |>
  merge(df)
  colA    colB      value x2008 x2009 x2010
1    A Stringn -29.893590  2.71  1.72  1.32
2    B Stringc   6.263441  3.10  1.68  2.66
3    C Stringb -16.180057  6.21  6.18  4.21
```